# Order by latitude and longitude

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, latitude-longitude

I am working on a project used to post adverts, this project is based on Localisation so when user post his adverts the application detect his position so when other people get intersted on his adverts they can finde him on Maps. The problem is that I want to order those adverts from the nearest one to the farest one using latitude and longitude of the adverts and also the latitude and longitude of the one who using the app

```
public function get_searched(Request $request){
    $annonce =DB::table('annonces')
    ->where('nomAnnonce','like','%'.$request->input("nomAnnonce").'%')
    ->orderby(((('latitude'- $request->input("lat"))*('latitude'-$request->input("lat"))) + (('longitude' - $request->input("lon"))*('longitude' - $request->input("lon")))), 'ASC')
    ->get();
    echo $annonce;}
```

This is all that I can do and that give me a wrong result:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ '1359.309643206' inconnu dans 
order clause (SQL: select * from `annonces` where `nomAnnonce` like %P% 
order by `1359`.`309643206` asc)
```

If anybody can help that's going to be a great pleasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
public function get_searched(Request $request){
    $annonces = DB::table("annonces")
    ->where('nomAnnonce','like','%'.$request->input("nomAnnonce").'%')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("3959 * acos( cos( radians({$request->input('lat')}) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-{$request->input('lon')}) ) + sin( radians({$request->input('lat')}) ) * sin(radians(latitude)) )"), 'ASC')
    ->get()
    dd($annonces);
}
```

This approach uses the Spherical Law of Cosines to get the distance

Comment: thnx sir , but there is syntax error, unexpected 'DB' (T_STRING) can you help please

Comment: @aymenmedjader you must be missing a `;`

Comment: thnnnnnnnnnnnnnnx sir thnx am crying right now . thanks to u i have finished my project thanks man i appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_searched(Request $request){
    $annonce =DB::table('annonces')
    ->select('*', 
    DB::raw(((('latitude'- $request->input("lat"))*('latitude'-$request->input("lat"))) + (('longitude' - $request->input("lon"))*('longitude' - $request->input("lon")))) 
            as 'distance'
            )
    ->where('nomAnnonce','like','%'.$request->input("nomAnnonce").'%')
    ->orderby('distance', 'ASC')
    ->get();
    echo $annonce;}
```

Comment: thnx sir , but there is syntax error, unexpected 'as' i didn't finde why !! some help

Comment: sorry, I'll fix it

Comment: it's still the same unexpected 'as' i think that as is not known by php as query builder in this case

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, I've worked on some projects that did very similar things, and put together a couple helper functions that can help.  There's an algorithm that calculates distances between two sets of coordinates, so these helpers will either execute that for you, or produce the SQL necessary to execute it within the database.  The `distance_sql()` one sounds like what you're looking for.  By making the query do the work instead of the script, you get the opportunity to sort and paginate the result-set before it comes back.  I'd recommend placing a [query-scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes) method in your model that calls on it.

If you haven't already done so, create an `app/helpers.php` file and add this to your `composer.json` file and then run `composer install`:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php",
        ...
    ],
    ...
},
...
```

And finally, place these in your `helpers.php`:

```
if (!function_exists('distance')) {
    /**
     * Calculate the distance between two sets of coordinates
     *
     * @param float $latitude1
     * @param float $longitude1
     * @param float $latitude2
     * @param float $longitude2
     * @param float $padding
     * @return float
     */
    function distance($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2, $padding = 0.0)
    {
        $earthRadiusInMiles = 3959;

        $latitude1 = deg2rad($latitude1);
        $latitude2 = deg2rad($latitude2);
        $longitude1 = deg2rad($longitude1);
        $longitude2 = deg2rad($longitude2);

        $miles = $earthRadiusInMiles * acos(
            cos($latitude1) * cos($latitude2)
            * cos($longitude2 - $longitude1)
            + sin($latitude1) * sin($latitude2)
        );

        $miles += $padding * $miles;

        return round($miles, 3);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('distance_sql')) {
    /**
     * Generate the SQL needed to calculate the distance between two sets of coordinates
     *
     * @param float|string $latitude1
     * @param float|string $longitude1
     * @param float|string $latitude2
     * @param float|string $longitude2
     * @param float $padding
     * @return string
     */
    function distance_sql($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2, $padding = 0.0)
    {
        $earthRadiusInMiles = 3959;

        $latitude1 = 'RADIANS('.DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($latitude1).')';
        $latitude2 = "RADIANS($latitude2)";
        $longitude1 = 'RADIANS('.DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($longitude1).')';
        $longitude2 = "RADIANS($longitude2)";

        $sql = "$earthRadiusInMiles * ACOS("
            . "COS($latitude1) * COS($latitude2)"
            . " * COS($longitude2 - $longitude1)"
            . " + SIN($latitude1) * SIN($latitude2))";

        $sql .= " + $padding * $sql";

        return $sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to call this function and use it from my finction 'get_searched' this is new for me can you please help more !!

Comment: Based on the presence of a Request object, I take it `get_searched` is a Controller method?  What you need here is a Model class.  See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions.  Use a Model class instead of the `DB` Facade whenever possible, especially for simple queries like this.  There's a lot of benefits Eloquent Models can offer that QueryBuilder (`DB`) on its own cannot.  Further elaboration on how to use Eloquent would be a much bigger discussion though, and one that has a lot of documentation behind it already, but that's where you should start.

Comment: Just as a side-note, couple pro-tips not made clear in the docs that may spare you some heartache later, since it sounds like you're not familiar with Eloquent yet.  1) Some method-calls will actually pass though a magic `__call()` method and actually return a QueryBuilder object instead of an Eloquent Model or Collection.  `join()` is one of them.  It's good to be aware of this.  2) Eager-loads, `with()` or `load()`, do not actually produce JOIN queries.  They produce entirely new queries that merely leverage `IN()` on the Ids returned from the main one.